# Regular expression match for specific lower_case php validation

Tags: php, regex

I need to compose a regular expression for string, with a max length of 6 characters, containing only Latin letters in lowercase, with an optional underscore separator, without underscore starting and trailing.

I tried the following

```
^[a-z_]{1,6}$
```

But it allows underscore at the start and the end.

I also tried:

```
^([a-z]_?[a-z]){1,6}$

^(([a-z]+)_?([a-z]+)){1,6}$

^([a-z](?:_?)[a-z]){1,6}$
```

But nothing works. Please help.

**Expecting:**

**Valid:**

ex_bar

**Not valid:**

_exbar

exbar_

_test_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would express your requirement as:

```
^(?!.{7,}$)[a-z](?:[a-z_]*[a-z])*$
```

This pattern matches:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `(?!.{7,}$)` assert that at most 6 characters are present
- `[a-z]` first letter must be `a-z`
- `(?:[a-z_]*[a-z])*` match `a-z` or underscore in the middle, but only `a-z` at the end
- `$` end of the string

Note that the behavior of the above pattern is that one character matches must be only letter `a-z`.  Similarly, two character matches can also only be `a-z` twice.  With three character matches and longer, it is possible for underscore to appear in the middle.

Here is a running [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FUgGn3/2).

Comment: This will also match strings of 8 'a-z' characters or more, as long as the string isn't bounded by underscores '_'

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly simple pattern that should work `^(?!_)[a-z_]{0,5}[a-z]$`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/3dPDe6/1) for a breakdown.

Comment: `with a max length of 6 characters` ... does your pattern match `a` or `ab` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, it does

Comment: [No it doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/oayRmZ/1).

Comment: @timbiegeleisen ah, it does in the regex101 I linked! Fixed - I removed the `0,` in the quantifier in a previous edit when I shouldn’t have. Good catch!

Comment: @bobblebubble - right on! That's a good tip; I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

`(?!^_)([a-z_]{6})(?<!_$)`

You could use a negative look-ahead and negative look-behind to ensure that the string doesn't start and end with an `_` underscore.

https://regex101.com/r/sMho0c/1

Comment: You can avoid lookbehind here by just using a class `[a-z]`

Comment: @JRiggles the performance would definitely be better in that case. I'll leave my answer, but you have my upvote!